# Get index position of where vector changes value

Tags: matlab

I have a vector that contains a list of strings which are ordered. I would like to know the index number of where the vector changes. Below is hopefully a clear example. I do not really use MATLAB much. In my head I'm just thinking of using a loop. I was wondering if there was a better way of doing this using MATLAB?

```
 Vector
 ABC
 ABC
 ABC
 ABC
 MNK
 MNK
 MNK
 PLO
 PLO
```

So I would like to know that ABC is from 1:4, MNK is from 5 : 7 & PLO is from 8 : 9

Comment: If you don't use MATLAB much - why now?

Comment: company decision, so learning but slowly!

Comment: Can you assume that strings are always sorted?

Comment: yes the strings will always be sorted

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One approach -

```
%%// Input
a1 = {
    'ABC'
    'ABC'
    'ABC'
    'ABC'
    'MNK'
    'MNK'
    'MNK'
    'PLO'
    'PLO'};

[val,x2] = unique(a1,'first');
[~,x12] = unique(a1); %%// By default takes the last unique value
out = [val num2cell(x2) num2cell(x12)]
```

Output -

```
out = 

    'ABC'    [1]    [4]
    'MNK'    [5]    [7]
    'PLO'    [8]    [9]
```

Comment: That's perfect! Cheers

Comment: "By default takes the last unique value": nice application of this!